# Missing WLAN settings after new installation of Ubuntu 20.04.3LTS on a laptop dual booting with Windows 11

Tags: networking, dual-boot

I just installed Ubuntu HP Pavillion laptop that already had windows 11 installed. During the installation, I did not get the option to pick a network to connect to, and once the installation was complete, there is no Wifi setting or switch for me to turn it on. I need help on how to get this fixed, I don't have access to an ethernet cable either.

I am still new to Linux so please keep that in mind, but I am also willing to get my hands dirty fixing this problem.

The Laptop is HP pavilion
AMD Ryzen 7 5700u
16gb RAM
Realtek WLAN RTL8852AE

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 has reached the end of life. It is not supported any more. Install a supported version of Ubuntu such as 22.04 LTS.

Comment: I have 20.04.3LTS, I installed that with the hope that it will be different. But I still have the same issue.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: You mention 20.04.3 LTS, but didn't specify which 20.04.3 product you installed.  If it was the Desktop release (and using a HWE kernel), you're using an *outdated & unsupported* kernel from an EOL release (21.04 or 5.11; older than 5.13 from 21.10) at least until upgrades are fully supported (*then your system will use a newer kernel but won't report as 20.04.3 any longer*).  Try a supported release of Ubuntu (20.04.5 is the latest, and uses the 5.4 (GA) kernel if using Server media, or 5.15 (HWE) kernel for Desktop (HWE). If asking about 20.04 (which is on-topic) please amend your question.

Comment: Did you try following any of the wifi troubleshooting docs?  eg. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide  Most useful (*in my opinion*) is the step 3 "*Device Recognition and Operation*" as it tells you what hardware exists in your machine (ie. chipset that allows wifi), which allows you to search for useful details online. You've provided no specifics on your hardware (eg. no brand/model/age of laptop)  that's commonly provided, but chips inside your box are even more useful  (*drivers* in Linux are kernel modules; being written for chips, not brand/model/OEM)

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format for the main products, ie. 21.10 tells you it was the 2021-October release (2000 is added to the *year*). The lastest such product is Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (ie. 2022-April; a LTS or *long-term-support* release.  There are also specialist *year* products (eg. Ubuntu Core 22) but they are *specialist* niche products. Non-LTS releases have 9 months of support; with a release every six months, giving users 3 months to *release-upgrade* their systems after the next comes out; LTS users however have a much longer cycle measured in years (2-5 years)

Comment: I have edited the question and added some description for my laptop and it's specifications.